# What is a definition ID of a JFace Action?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

The jface.Action class has a setActionDefinitionId method. I would like to know what this is used for.

The following is from the setAccelerator javadoc:

> If you set an accelerator using this method, then it will not work in the workbench if it conflicts any existing key binding, or if there is a different key binding defined for this **action's definition id**. The **definition id** should be used instead -- referring to the command in the workbench from which the key binding should be retrieved.

I couldn't find any relevant information about the definition id anywhere I looked.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action definition ID is used to bind an action to a command. If the ID of the command is set as action definition ID of the action, the action is regarded as a handler for the command.

This is useful if you want to migrate your Eclipse application from using actions to using the command framework. It allows to do a smooth migration because you can reuse parts of your existing code without having to convert all actions to command handlers.

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_associate_an_action_with_a_command%3F for more information.